# AWS-Lambda function (Python) to copy file from S3 - perform manipulation - store output in another S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking for some guidance, if someone can put me in right direction.

Scenario: Have to write a Lambda function in Python that would be capable of performing following tasks;

1. Lambda is triggered when file is copied to S3 bucket A.
2. Lambda is able to distinguish from file name or content what logic to trigger.
3. Lambda copies the file to S3 bucket B.
4. Lambda performs processing according to file name or content and stores output in another file in S3 bucket C.

For the above if you can guide which python library we can use, any functions that can make this task easier. I am not much experienced with Python so any sample code would also be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This code can all be run using the python boto3 library in a lambda handler function (`def lambda_handler(event, context):`).
You must set an s3 client to copy objects or write to a bucket

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

#### 1. Lambda is triggered when file is copied to S3 bucket A.

```
# Get the S3 bucket name and object key from the event
bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
object_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

if bucket_name == 'A':
    # code
```

#### 2. Lambda is able to distinguish from file name or content what logic to trigger.

```
# Check if the file ends with "_passed.csv" and the bucket name is 'A'
if bucket_name == 'A' and object_key.endswith('_passed.csv'):
    # trigger logic here
```

#### 3. Lambda copies the file to S3 bucket B.

```
copy_source = {'Bucket': 'A', 'Key': 'folder/file'}
s3.copy_object(CopySource = copy_source, Bucket = 'B', Key = 'folder/file')
```

#### 4. Lambda performs processing according to file name or content and stores output in another file in S3 bucket C.

The selective logic done using if statements (shown above), to store ouput in s3 bucket C:

```
content="output to put in another file"
s3.Object('C', 'put_in_bucket_C.txt').put(Body=content)
```

Comment: Thanks Caro, that's really helpful. Shall follow these steps to progress the code development.